# Adding existing xml to existing xml document

Tags: c#, xml

This a simple xml document

```
<parent>
<control> </control>
<option>
  <data>
  </data>
</option>
</parent>
```

I want to insert certain elements under the `data` element under `option`

This is the code I have written

```
XDocument xml2 = new XDocument();
            xml2 = XDocument.Parse(xEvent); //containing the above xml

            foreach(var element in xml2.Descendants())
            {
                if(element.Name == "Options")
                {
                    foreach(var element2 in element.Descendants())
                    {
                        if(elment.Name == 'Data')
                        {
                           //what to put in here? I want to insert the already made xml document
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is the final xml that I want

```
 <Data>
    <TemplateID>xxxxx</TemplateID>
    <CaptionOptions>
        <CaptionField>
             <Field>xxx</Field>
             <Text>xxx</Text>
        </CaptionField>
        <CaptionField>            //All these are already present in a string/xml doc
              <Field>xxxx</Field>
              <Text>""</Text>
         </CaptionField>
         </CaptionOptions>
    </Data>
```

What to do????

Comment: @Flater changed my question

Comment: Xml element names are case sensitive. `data` not equals `Data` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. I have used `XML to LINQ` approach.

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using static System.Console;

string xml = @"<parent>
                    <control></control>
                    <option>
                      <data>
                      </data>
                    </option>
                    </parent>";

            // First let us parse the xml string using XElement
            var parsedXML = XElement.Parse(xml);

            // Now get the element from the <option>  tag.
            var firstElement = parsedXML.Element("option").Descendants().First();
            firstElement.Add(new XElement("TemplateID", "xxxx"));
            firstElement.Add(new XElement("CaptionOptions"));

            // You will use for loop here
            //{ 
            //firstElement.Element("CaptionOptions").Descendants().First().Add(new XElement("CaptionField"));
            firstElement.Element("CaptionOptions").Add(new XElement("CaptionField",
                                                           new XElement("Field", "xxxx"),
                                                           new XElement("Text", "hello")
                                                      ));

            //}
            WriteLine(parsedXML.ToString());
```

and final xml looks something like this -

```
<parent>
  <control></control>
  <option>
    <data>
      <TemplateID>xxxx</TemplateID>
      <CaptionOptions>
        <CaptionField>
          <Field>xxxx</Field>
          <Text>hello</Text>
        </CaptionField>
      </CaptionOptions>
    </data>
  </option>
</parent>
```